# Turning off connection pool for Go http.Client

Tags: go

For testing purposes I'm trying to create a `net/http.Client` in Go that has connection pooling disabled. What I'm trying to achieve is a new TCP connection is established to the address on every HTTP/1.x request.

Currently I have:

```
        c = &http.Client{
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                    Timeout:   5 * time.Second,
                    KeepAlive: 5 * time.Second,
                }).DialContext,
                TLSHandshakeTimeout:   5 * time.Second,
                ResponseHeaderTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
                ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
            },
        }
```

Any ideas how should I tweak this?

I'm seeing that if I set `c.Transport.MaxIdleConns = 1` this could work, but I'm not exactly sure if this still allows 1 in-use + 1 idle (2 total) TCP connections:

```
    // MaxIdleConns controls the maximum number of idle (keep-alive)
    // connections across all hosts. Zero means no limit.
    MaxIdleConns int
```

Similarly, it seems like `c.Dialer.KeepAlive = -1` could do this, too:

```
    // KeepAlive specifies the keep-alive period for an active
    // network connection.
    // If zero, keep-alives are enabled if supported by the protocol
    // and operating system. Network protocols or operating systems
    // that do not support keep-alives ignore this field.
    // If negative, keep-alives are disabled.
```

but I'm not sure about the behavior for TCP connections + Keep-Alive + HTTP.

Another approach is to try to kill idle TCP connections as soon as possible, so I set `c.Transport.IdleConnTimeout = 1*time.Nanosecond`.

When I did this, my `Client.Do()` now occassionally returns error:

```
tls: use of closed connection
```

I'm suspecting this is a Go stdlib issue (perhaps a race) that it uses a connection that should've been taken out of a pool.

Comment: Do you need to have only one client? The most straightforward way to do this is simply have a function which returns a new client object that you can use.

Comment: @Jesse, if you do only that, then you will leak open tcp connections

Comment: Why not just close the connection, and not worry about the pool? Have you tried using [`Request.Close`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) (or set the `Connection: close` header)?

Comment: @JimB If it's for testing purposes that may not be a concern.

Comment: Any of these could work. Mind adding as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Connections are added to the pool in the function [Transport.tryPutIdleConn](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c333d07ebe9268efc3cf4bd68319d65818c75966/src/net/http/transport.go#L819).  The connection is not pooled if [Transport.DisableKeepAlives](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport.DisableKeepAlives) is true or  [Transport.MaxIdleConnsPerHost](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport.MaxIdleConnsPerHost) is less than zero.

Setting either value disables pooling. The transport adds the `Connection: close` request header when DisableKeepAlives is true. This may or may not be desirable depending on what you are testing.

Here's how to set DisableKeepAlives:

```
t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
t.DisableKeepAlives = true
c := &http.Client{Transport: t}
```

[Run a demonstration of DisableKeepAlives = true on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yIJLbSZ-kHg).

Here's how to set MaxIdleConnsPerHost:

```
t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
t.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = -1
c := &http.Client{Transport: t}
```

[Run a demonstration of MaxIdleConnsPerHost = -1 on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0aBzZ0fK_lZ).

The code above [clones](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport.Clone) the default transport to ensure that the default transport options are used. If you explicitly want the options in the question, then use

```
    c = &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   5 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 5 * time.Second,
            }).DialContext,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout:   5 * time.Second,
            ResponseHeaderTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
            ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
            DisableKeepAlives: true,
        },
    }
```

or

```
    c = &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   5 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 5 * time.Second,
            }).DialContext,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout:   5 * time.Second,
            ResponseHeaderTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
            ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
            MaxIdleConnsPerHost: -1,
        },
    }
```

MaxIdleConnsPerHost does not limit the number of active connections per host.  [See this playground example for a demonstration](https://play.golang.org/p/6eJg0mY8ZXr).

Pooling is not disabled by setting  [Dialer.KeepAlive](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer.KeepAlive) to -1. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656164/what-is-the-difference-between-net-dialerkeepalive-and-http-transportidletimeo/59656223#59656223) for an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `DisableKeepAlives` to `true`, and `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` to -1.

From the documentation:

```
// DisableKeepAlives, if true, disables HTTP keep-alives and
// will only use the connection to the server for a single
// HTTP request.
```

https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go, line 166 and 187

So, your client have to be initialized as following

```golang
c = &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   5 * time.Second,
        }).DialContext,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   5 * time.Second,
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
        DisableKeepAlives: true,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: -1
    },
}
```

If you are using a Go version prior than 1.7, than you need to consume all the buffer of the body and only after call the `request.Body.Close()`. Instead, if you are using a version greater or equal the 1.7, you can defer the close without additional precautions.

Example library that has connection pooling disabled, but is still able to perform parallel requests:
https://github.com/alessiosavi/Requests

Comment: Do you have a reference to the changes in 1.7 that made consuming the buffer unnecessary? I can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

The http.Transport has a property called `MaxConnsPerHost`

> MaxConnsPerHost optionally limits the total number of connections per host, including connections in the dialing, active, and idle states.

It includes the dialing, active and idle states

Comment: This doesn't help because once I make a request causing a connection to `example.com`, I need that connection to go away, so that next request uses dials from scratch. However, setting `MaxConnsPerHost:1` will still reuse that one TCP connection.