# What is the difference between net.Dialer#KeepAlive and http.Transport#IdleTimeout?

Tags: http, go, network-programming

```
type Dialer struct {
    ......
    // KeepAlive specifies the keep-alive period for an active
    // network connection.
    // If zero, keep-alives are enabled if supported by the protocol
    // and operating system. Network protocols or operating systems
    // that do not support keep-alives ignore this field.
    // If negative, keep-alives are disabled.
    KeepAlive time.Duration
}
```

```
type Transport struct {
    ......
// IdleConnTimeout is the maximum amount of time an idle
    // (keep-alive) connection will remain idle before closing
    // itself.
    // Zero means no limit.
    IdleConnTimeout time.Duration
}
```

I think keep-alive is a time that the tcp connection shoud keep. But IdleConnTimeout seems like the same thing. So what the difference between them and if I both set up these varible, the tcp connection can keep how long?

Comment: The TCP keeplaive time is the time between keepalive probes. It isn't an idle timeout. The other is.

Comment: The descriptions you quote answer the question. They are nothing alike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term keep-alive means different things in the two contexts.

The net/http Transport documentation uses the term to refer to [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection). A keep-alive or persistent connection is a connection that can be used for more than one HTTP transaction.

The [Transport.IdleConnTimeout](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport.IdleConnTimeout) field specifies how long the transport keeps an unused connection in the pool before closing the connection.

The net Dialer documentation uses the keep-alive term to refer the [TCP feature for probing the health of a connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_keepalive).

[Dialer.KeepAlive](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer.KeepAlive) field specifies how frequently TCP keep-alive probes are sent to the peer.

The two settings do different things at different layers in the stack.

Comment: Thanks!  So Dialer.KeepAlive is uesd to probe tcp connection health period, and Transport.IdleConnTimeout  is how long can I reuse the tcp connection. The first one is work TCP and the second one is work on HTTP. Is it right?